# Disconnecting RC/RL-Circuit prematurely

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

Lately I've been dealing with some RC/RL Circuits, and as I was working on a problem, I came across a peculiar issue, which I haven't properly resolved so far.
The given equations that describe $i(t),\;u_{C/L}(t)$ and $u_R(t)$ do so in dependence on $U_0$, that being the initial Voltage at the battery.
To me this makes sense, as long as the capacitor/inductor has had the time to fully charge/stop inducing. But what I don't fully understand, is what happens when the Battery is disconnected prematurely from the circuit. Which value do I insert for $U_0$? Either way, Kirchhoff's law needs to be satisfied, which implies that the given Voltages we're left with for $u_R$ and $u_{C/L}$ need to be opposite to one another, but I can't find a satisfactory explanation for what values I should logically continue working with. I hope my question is clear enough, and if not, I can clarify further if needed.

I've never asked a question on here before, nor am I particularly experienced; but so far, I simply haven't been able to find any sufficient explanations on the topic.

Comment: Which equations are you talking about, specifically? And which timescales? The value of $u_\text{C}(t)$ for a long time after connecting $U_0$ surely is a bit boring, as it will just be constant.

Comment: Example:   $i(t) \;=\; \frac{U_0}{R} \;\cdot\; e^{-tR/L}$   which is the current in a RL-Circuit after disconnection of the battery. Like I said, if the battery is disconnected prematurely, it's not clear to me what happens to the voltages and the current in the circuit. Both $u_L$ and $u_R$ will then be unequal to $U_0$, so what will be the "new" $U_0$?. After all, the formulas are expressed in dependence on that value, not any other. Also, I'm dealing with ms as the timescale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given no information on the circuit you are dealing with, one can only provide some general rules.

Plug in the value $t=t_{o}$ into your equations for voltages and currents as a function of time where $t_{o}$ is the time when the battery is disconnected. Then

1. Whatever the voltage is across a capacitor at $t=t_o$ it will the same the instant the battery is disconnected. This is because you can't change the voltage across a capacitor in zero time and energy will be stored in the electric field of the capacitor.
2. Whatever the current is in an inductor at $t=t_o$ it will the same the instant the battery is disconnected. This is because you can't change the current in an inductor in zero time and energy will be stored in the magnetic field of the inductor.
3. The current in and voltage across a resistor at $t=t_o$ will be dictated by the values of 1 and 2 and Kirchhoff's laws.

For time $t>t_o$ you will have need new equations as a function of time for transients where there is no battery in the circuit and where the initial values of currents and voltages will be those of 1 through 3 above.

An anomaly occurs if you attempt to open a switch to the battery for a series RL circuit. The open switch is theoretically an infinite resistance so in order to satisfy condition 2 above, you would need an infinite voltage induced across the switch gap to maintain the current. In practice this can't happen and instead the inductor induces a sufficiently high voltage to cause arcing across the gap and a breakdown of the air, which together with the series resistor dissipates the energy of the magnetic field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; this is exactly what I was looking for. The thing I was so confused about was the difference between $u_R$ and $u_L$, as in which one of the two dictates the Voltage once the battery is gone. To me it just looked like there are two options: either $u_L$ takes on the value of $u_R$ or the other way around. Your answer completely cleares up that ambiguity.

Comment: See my. update re series RL circuit.